# How to build synchronous code containing a promise

Tags: angularjs, promise, q

I have this function:

```
var send = function send (report) {
        someAsnycFn().then(
            function () {
                synchronousSend(report);
                return true;

            }, function () {
                throw new Error("The user is not authenticated! Not sending report");
            });
    };
```

My goal is to have the `send` function block the code execution until the promise is resolved and then execute the according code block and continue code execution.

I guess for example in C# you would use [await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh156528.aspx) for this...

How can i do that in JS?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Your `send` function should **`return`** a promise!

Comment: Why? I don't want to change my code in order satisfy my testing-framework.

Comment: This is not to satisfy a testing framework, but the functionality of your app. If you reject a promise that is not returned, nobody will be able to handle the rejection - the `throw` cannot be caught (neither in your test, nor in your actual code).

Comment: Well, `someAsyncFn` is returning a promise, as you can see. Now I want to get `send` synchronous, because I have to stop my code execution in order to be able to catch the error for example.
The problem is not, that I don't _know_ how to make the `send` function asnchronous (with a promise), but that I don't want it to be asynchronous. It should block until the promise is fulfilled and then execute the appropriate code block.

Comment: You _have_ to return the promise unless you want to block the entire process> Everything is handled with callbacks and there is only one thread running the JavaScript itself, that's the nature of the language. If you want to execute code when `send` completes, make it return the promise, and then whoever uses send can use the promise.

Comment: @Sentenza: "*Now I want to get send synchronous*" - that's impossible. You don't really want to make code blocking. Promises are not a tool to switch between sync and async, they are a tool to make async callbacks more composable and maintainable.

Comment: @Louis i forgot to remove these tags, since my orinal question was how to test against that error.

Comment: @Bergi I see that promises wont provide the solution for me here. But the use case is actually not that uncommon. Maybe thats why they define async/await-Sytanx for ECMAscript 7...

Comment: @Sentenza ES7 async/await awaits promises, just so you know.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum what do you mean? `someAsyncFn` returns a promise.

Answer (score 1):

After further research I actually have found two solutions to this problem:

1. Using Providers and `yield`: The [galaxy-lib](https://github.com/bjouhier/galaxy) wraps these in order to use them like asnyc/await.
2. ECMAscript 7 [defines `async/await`-Syntax](https://github.com/lukehoban/ecmascript-asyncawait). With that I would be able to just do:

   ```
   asnyc function send (report) {
       await someAsyncFn().catch(throw new Error("The user is not authenticated! Not sending report"));
       synchronousSend(report);
       return true;
   }
   ```

Problem is, that I'm still working in ECMAscript 5, thus i cannot use it (in a production environment). My temporary solution will be to actually turn `send` into an async function returning a promise.

Comment: Better turn `send` into an async function, you will eventually need to do this anyway.

Comment: Look into facebook's regenerator.